# Out parameter in an HttpGet - ASP.NET Web API

Tags: asp.net-web-api, out

Can you have an out parameter for an `HttpGet` in ASP.NET WebAPI? If so, what would the URI look like for this call?

```
[HttpGet]
public HttpResponseMessage Query(string mask, out List<Int> Ids)
```

Comment: Why would you ever need that?

Comment: I was asked to finish someone else's project and the code was littered with out parameters in http operations. Since there were so many, I was hesitant to assume that he had just implemented the the entire thing incorrectly

Answer (score 2):

No. The `HTTPResponseMessage` `Content` property is used for returning a payload.